# In .NET, is it appropriate to invoke BeginSendTo in the callback?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm using the .NET Socket interface with BeginSendTo(). In my callback that I pass to that function, I call EndSendTo() and then call BeginSendTo() from within that callback. Is that OK to do? I don't seem to find this type of implementation in the examples I see.

```
/// <summary>
/// The message queue in which incoming log messages are placed. These are emptied
/// during appropriate socket callbacks
/// </summary>
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Message> MessageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Message>();

/// <summary>
/// The message sent callback. Calls EndSendTo on the socket and continues processing the
/// message queue.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ar">The AsyncResult</param>
private void MessageSent(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  var bytesSent = Socket.EndSendTo(ar);
  SendFromMessageQueue();
}

/// <summary>
/// Begins sending the message on the socket
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to send</param>
private void BeginSendMessageOnSocket(Message message)
{
  var data = BinarySerialize(message);
  Socket.BeginSendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, RemoteEndPoint, this.MessageSent,
    message);
}

/// <summary>
/// Starts sending messages from the message queue
/// </summary>
private void SendFromMessageQueue()
{
  while (MessageQueue.TryDequeue(out var message))
  {
    BeginSendMessageOnSocket(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: See msdn example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example :

Comment: @jdweng, they're using `Send` and `Receive` instead of `SendTo` and `ReceiveFrom`. Can you make an answer somewhere along the lines of, "An example does exist here... ...the usage of Send and SentTo is the same with regards to asynchronous operation". Then when someone is searching for SendTo examples, they might find the Send example through my question.

Comment: The names of the Event Method can be any name you choose.  The important names are the CallBack and BeginSendTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine to do.  All the examples I can find are based on TCP so they use `BeginSend()` and `EndSend()`.  But the same callback principles apply and so `BeginSendTo()` and `EndSendTo()` can be used in the same way.

They both use the IOCP thread pool to do the IO.